# sigaction for SIGINT, SA_RESETHAND

Tags: linux, unix, signals, handler, sigaction

Is there a way to handle SIGINT only 2 times and return it to default using SA_RESETHAND? We must use sigaction, and make our handler reinstall by itself 2 times and then install flags to resethand. But there's a question: how to reinstall my handler only 2 times and how to use RESETHAND in this situation? n-1?

```
void sig_int(int sig)
{
    printf(" -> Ctrl-C\n");
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = sig_int;

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Put a counter in a global variable, and increment it in the handler. When it reaches `2`, don't re-establish the handler.

Comment: But what about sa_resethand? How can I put it with n-1 step?

Comment: Instead of `SA_RESETHAND`, why not leave the handler, and then remove it when you reach the limit?

Comment: finally it works and i used resethand, but you helped a lot! Thank you!!!

Comment: Post an answer showing the solution.